# How to multiply NumberDecimal values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

I have the following structure:

```
{
            "_id": "5d0118f0f57a282f89bc5f71",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5cfed37375a13067dd01ddb7",
                "name": "My product",
                "description": "My description",
                "purchased_amount": 15,
                "unit_price_mex": "45",
                "unit_price_to_sell": "5",
                "travel": "5cf58713d6f7f1657e2d8302",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5cfed37375a13067dd01ddb7"
            },
            "client": {
                "_id": "5cf1778efffb651fad89d8b6",
                "name": "Client name",
                "description": "",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "purchased_amount": 3,
            "fch": "13/6/2019",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d0151afda1a446008f1817b",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5cfed1995eaf2665c45efd82",
                "name": "Camisa",
                "description": "Camisas buenas",
                "purchased_amount": 10,
                "unit_price_mex": "100",
                "unit_price_to_sell": "15",
                "travel": "5cf56b04462a865264fabb9d",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5cfed1995eaf2665c45efd82"
            },
            "client": {
                "_id": "5cf1778efffb651fad89d8b6",
                "name": "Randy",
                "description": "El que trabaja aqui",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "purchased_amount": 34,
            "fch": "12/6/2019",
            "__v": 0
        },
```

Where client and product are of type ObjectId. This is the Schema:

**Client Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');


var clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String
    }).plugin(mongoosePaginate);

var Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

module.exports = Client;
```

**Product Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String,
        purchased_amount: Number,
        unit_price_mex: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128,
        unit_price_to_sell: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128, 
        travel: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Travel' }
    }).plugin(mongoosePaginate);

productSchema.set('toJSON', {
        getters: true,
        transform: (doc, ret) => {
            if (ret.unit_price_mex) {
                ret.unit_price_mex = ret.unit_price_mex.toString();
            }
            if ( ret.unit_price_to_sell ) {
                ret.unit_price_to_sell = ret.unit_price_to_sell.toString();
            }
        }
    })

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

I need to get the multiplication sum of purchased_amount by product.unit_price_to_sell. My code is the following but always returns 0. Apparently, "$product.unit_price_to_sell" does not return the decimal value.

```
    var aggregate = InvoiceModel.aggregate([
        { $match: { client: mongoose.Types.ObjectId( id ) } },
        { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$purchased_amount", "$product.unit_price_to_sell" ] } } } }
    ]);
    InvoiceModel.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, {}, (error, aggs) => {
        InvoiceModel.paginate({ client: id },{ page, limit, populate: 'client product' }, (err, value) => {
            return res.status(200).send({
                results: value.docs,
                totalPages: value.totalPages,
                totalDocs: value.totalDocs,
                purchase_amount_total : aggs.docs[0].total
            })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB cannot use string values in arithmetic expressions. You must either store the values using their numeric non-string representations, or you must use an aggregation operator like `$toDecimal` to convert the values to their numeric representations first.

Modifying your `$group` stage to something like the following should work:

```
{ $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$purchased_amount", { $toDecimal: "$product.unit_price_to_sell" } ] } } }
```

Please note, however, that this will only work for MongoDB versions >= 4.0. If you're using an older version of MongoDB, you will either need to upgrade it to at least version 4.0 or begin converting your existing values from strings to numbers.

Comment: Thanks but my MongoDB version is 3.6.

Comment: This $product.unit_price_to_sell not return a value.

Comment: I've already mentioned that you will have to either 1. upgrade your MongoDB version to 4.0, or 2. update all of your documents so that `product.unit_price_to_sell` is a numeric value instead of a string. Otherwise, you can do option 3. which is to calculate these values on the server side rather than in the aggregation pipeline. These are your only options.

Comment: The best solution I found was to change the type of the Product field. Previously I had it in a referential way and I have changed it to embedded. I have learned that the referential form should only be used when you are only going to populate. If you are going to access their properties, you must declare it in an embedded form.